# Liferay: Cannot delete users or themes, or sites

Tags: database, liferay

From one day to the other I was not able to delete anything in my Liferay portal. I cant do it using API nor via Control Panel. I tried restarting the server, clearing database cache and re indexing all search indexes. Any Suggestions?

My logs contain:

```
16:12:27,261 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-4][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortletImpl.getPortletDataHandlerInstance(PortletImpl.java:1395)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.deletePortletData(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:3687)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.deleteGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:852)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.deleteUser(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:1836)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.deleteUser(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:1806)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser(UserServiceImpl.java:719)
```

Comment: Please be more specific:  Is there any error message in the browser or in the log, can you still create things, what about web content and the trash?

Comment: I can still create things. the only problem is deleting. I just added the logs, What do you think might have happened? thanks@TobiasLiefke

Comment: It seems that one of the portlets is not registered correctly - did you uninstall a portlet recently or are there other exceptions in the log (during startup) already? You could set a breakpoint in `PortletImpl.java:1395` as well and check which portlet is creating the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your settings for sites.

I had the problem that sites could not be updated or deleted after upgrade to  Liferay Portal 6.2 CE GA4 from Liferay 6.1.2

I found that this was caused by a bug. I had disabled the display settings for sites in portal-ext.properties. Upgrade and delete worked again after enabling the display setting for sites, i.e.,
 "sites.form.add.miscellaneous=display-settings" and
"sites.form.update.miscellaneous=display-settings,custom-fields"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It looks like it was a portlet that was giving out an error. 
 at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortletImpl.getPortletDataHandlerInstance(PortletImpl.java:1395)

So I Recreated it and the problem got fixed.